# Anaconda for linux 32 bit OS

Tags: linux, anaconda, 32bit-64bit

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-anaconda-on-ubuntu-18-04-quickstart

Using this link,I followed steps and I could download Anaconda 64 bit, however my Computer OS is 32 bit. I am using Linux.

```
   $ cd /tmp
   $ curl -O https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2019.03-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

I want the link to Anaconda 32 bit after curl -O. In the Anaconda distribution link https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/#linux there are only python with 64 bit OS links.

Currently Python 2.7 is installed on my computer.
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at https://repo.anaconda.com/archive it seems anaconda has stopped providing 32-bit x86 Linux packages. The latest 32-bit x86 Linux package seems to be https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda2-2018.12-Linux-x86.sh

(You might want to consider upgrading to x86-64 Linux yourself as well, but that's a separate topic)

Comment: Thank you. Actually for a project my team works on Linux, so using old laptop with Linux for easy installations and access etc. My current laptop has windows